# How to supress chktex errors in minted environment?

Tags: minted, chktex

Is there a way to make chktex play nice with the minted package? Right now, it seems to assume that normal checks apply to the content of the minted environments and produces a lot of warnings.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Prepare a file called `chktexrc.local` in the same directory as the file you have to check, containing

```
VerbEnvir
{
    verbatim comment listing verbatimtab rawhtml errexam picture texdraw
    filecontents pgfpicture tikzpicture minted
}
```

Call

```
chktex -l chktexrc.local filename.tex
```

(where `filename` stands for the name of the file, of course).

I tested it with the file `gregoire.tex`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}
\begin{document}

\begin{minted}
a{zxx
\end{minted}

\end{document}
```

and the normal call of `chktex gregoire.tex` gives

```
ChkTeX v1.7.4 - Copyright 1995-96 Jens T. Berger Thielemann.
Compiled with POSIX extended regex support.
Warning 15 in  line 6: No match found for `{'.

 ^
Warning 17 in gregoire.tex line 9: Number of `{' doesn't match the number of `}'!
```

whereas the call `chktex -l chktexrc.local gregoire.tex` produces

```
ChkTeX v1.7.4 - Copyright 1995-96 Jens T. Berger Thielemann.
Compiled with POSIX extended regex support.
No errors printed; No warnings printed; No user suppressed warnings; No line suppressed warnings.
```

---

Note: the `VerbEnvir` list in the default `chktexrc` file doesn't cover several other “verbatim-like” environments; it has been updated for `pgfpicture` and `tikzpicture`, but it misses several other common environments such as those provided by `listings` and `fancyvrb`. However, the list cannot be complete, as these packages allow for defining new environments; probably adding

```
Verbatim BVerbatim lstlistings
```

would be useful nonetheless.

Comment: If you call it `.chktexrc` (or `chktexrc` on Windows), you don't have to use the `-l` option, it will be picked up automatically.

Comment: @IvanAndrus Sure, but I don't like the proliferation of invisible files.

Comment: Should be `lstlisting` instead of `listings`.

Comment: @RaffiKhatchadourian The code is simply copied from the default `chktexrc` file with the addition of `minted`. If one wants to also cover `lstlisting`, also this name must be added; but the question didn't mention it. I'm displeased by the downvote, but the answer is correct as it stands.

Comment: I don't think there is a listing environment. The package is called listing but the environment is lstlistings.

Comment: @RaffiKhatchadourian You probably don't know about the `listing` package: https://www.ctan.org/pkg/listing I don't think `listings` was available when `chktex` was being developed.

Comment: That is the same package. The package name should not be in the ignore clause.

Comment: @RaffiKhatchadourian Please, read *carefully*: the `listing` package is *different* from the `listings` package and it provides the `listing` environment. Anyway, I added a note about that.

Comment: Oh ok if that's the case, if you add lstlistings to your answer that would be great. Thanks.

Comment: What about ignoring `\mintinline`?

Comment: Actually, I found a default file here that seems to take care of this problem: http://ftp.isu.edu.tw/pub/Unix/CTAN/support/chktex/chktexrc.

Comment: @RaffiKhatchadourian You can add `\mintinline:{}{}` to the `WipeArg` list and `\mintinline{python}{print(x**2)}` would be ignored. Otherwise it just warns about a parenthesis without a space in front of it.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the default chktexrc found [here](http://ftp.isu.edu.tw/pub/Unix/CTAN/support/chktex/chktexrc) (store in your directory as `.chktexrc` or use the global one). I changed the following in this file to accommodate the minted package:

```
VerbEnvir
{
    verbatim comment listing lstlisting verbatimtab rawhtml errexam picture texdraw minted
}

WipeArg
{
    \label:{} \ref:{} \vref:{} \pageref:{} \index:{} \cite:[]{}
    \input:{} \verbatiminput:[]{} \listinginput:[]{}{}
    \verbatimtabinput:[]{} \include:{} \includeonly:{} 
    \bibitem:[]{} \mintinline:[]{}{}
}
```